# Testing Typescript with Jest in Visual Studio code does not show proper source code lines

Tags: typescript, debugging, visual-studio-code, jestjs

I have tried to get Jest to run properly in Visual Studio code.  While I can debug Typescript without an issue, I am unable to get to the proper lines on included functions with Jest.

I have a test file that imports my module:

```
import { Validate } from "./validate";

describe('Test the Validate', () => {
    it('should return true', () => {
        expect(Validate('abc')).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it('should return false', () => {
        expect(Validate('cba')).toBeFalsy();
    });
});
```

validate.ts:

```
export function Validate(Text:string):boolean {
    if (Text === 'abc') {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I place a break point on the `expect(Validate('abc')).toBeTruthy();` line, which does seem to cause the code to stop.  When I press F11 to step into the function, I do go to the source file, but my cursor is at the end of the file.  I can seem to move along with F10 to do the debugging, but I do not see a proper source line.

I have added `sourceMaps: true,` to my launch.json.

launch.json

```
{
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "Jest Current File",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/jest",
    "args": ["${relativeFile}"],
    "console": "integratedTerminal",
    "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
    "sourceMaps": true,
    "windows": {
          "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/jest/bin/jest",
    }
}
```

Also, using ts-jest like below did not change the outcome:

```
{
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "Jest Current File",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/ts-jest",
    "args": ["${relativeFile}"],
    "console": "integratedTerminal",
    "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
    "sourceMaps": true,
    "windows": {
          "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/jest/bin/jest",
    }
```

Comment: try using https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest instead of jest

Comment: Changing the "program" to be `"program":"${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/ts-jest"` had no effect.  I updated my example with this change.